# Architecture to allow third party apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

I am trying to develop an web application on Ruby on Rails. I would like to allow third party developers to develop app for my application(similar to Facebook app). Could you guys please suggest an architecture?

Comment: Consider Facebook, which allow apps like branchout run inside facebook. It is been developed by third party and they able to host the app inside Facebook. Similarly I am developing an application on JRuby on Rails where I should be able to allow third party developers to develop app for my appliction. I am not looking for REST APIs where third party websites can extend it and integrate in to their app.

Comment: you should edit your question to include the information in your comment. Hopefully you'll include some paragraph breaks (which we can't see in your comment). In any case, this is still vague, and you're asking for a lot, with hardly any indication of what your research has found, but Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a vague question. He want to make their users capable to create they own apps like the Facebook. I have the same issue for one Rails 3 App and, the only reference I've found at this moment are:

[Can users sign up for my app via facebook on a third-party site using my api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060822/can-users-sign-up-for-my-app-via-facebook-on-a-third-party-site-using-my-api)

[integration_api - SSO plugin between Rails and other web apps such as Beast, Wordpress, or PunBB.](https://github.com/gravis/integration_api)

The first link explains the minimum idea, and the second one are a Rails 2 plugin that can help to allow third party apps. However, its need to upgraded to a recent version (or in my case to Rails 3.2.13) before use integration_api.

Please, let me know if you've found other ways.