# Can users sign up for my app via facebook on a third-party site using my api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a rails application that allows third party sites to embed my widget on their site. Part of the functionality of my app requires people to 'link up' their facebook accounts. Can this be done through a widget? Can they link up facebook to my app through a widget on a third-party site?

Answer (score 2):

It should work if

- your widget is in an iframe (so the window location url matches the one you set for facebook oauth)
- and you use client side oauth (you don't want to overwrite top.location)

Why don't you try it and come back if you have any problems